# Can't remember which quest I'm on

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm currently in the Terminus Cave and I've just got the TM next to that cart thing. I haven't played in a couple of months and I can't remember what I am doing. Can anyone help?

Comment: How many badges do you currently have?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: That question and its answer only apply to Sun & Moon, while this question is about X & Y.

Comment: @jwodder Yeah, I didn't see that at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you've entered the Hall of Fame then you have access to the last chamber, where you can catch the legendary Pokemon hidden there:

> Zygarde

Otherwise an Ace Trainer will block you. In this case you need to continue the story, exit the cave and proceed south to Couriway Town.